# Averaging ages across a list with foldl (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am doing some arbitrary operations in Haskell as I learn, and have been playing with a list of animals with certain properties, including age.

This is my script:

```
module Animals where

data Animal = CatThing String Int
            | DogThing String Int
            deriving Show

animalList :: [Animal]
animalList = [CatThing "Spot" 2, DogThing "Rex" 5]

-- write a function that returns the string component given an animal
getName :: Animal -> String
getName (CatThing name _) = name
getName (DogThing name _) = name 

-- get the age of an animal (uses "map")
getAge :: Animal -> Int
getAge (CatThing _ age) = age
getAge (DogThing _ age) = age

-- sum age
sumAge :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
sumAge _ [b, c] = foldl (+) 0 [b, c]

-- average age
???
```

I am stuck on how to sum using `foldl'`.  I know there is a `sum` function built in, but I am really trying to practice folds, so am trying to do it that way.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: The code of `sumAge` looks fine to me. What's the problem that you see?

Comment: Try `sumAge _ ages = foldl (+) 0 ages` - your current pattern `[b, c]` only matches two-element lists. Also, what's the unused parameter for?

Comment: The average is just the sum divided by the length. Each of those can be implemented by a fold, but the average itself can't. (Unless you do both folds "at once" by having it return a tuple, then combine the two elements at the end m)

Comment: @RobinZigmond You can use the recursive formula for average values of a sequence to use a fold instead of a tuple, since `m[i+1] = (i * m[i] + x[i+1]) / (i+1)`, but it does require using a sequence instead of a list so you can access indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for your sum looks fine, I'd use `foldl'` instead of `foldl` so you don't risk a stack overflow, and also change that `[b,c]` pattern to a generic variable or even better point free so it looks better and it's also more general:

```
sumAge :: [Double] -> [Double]
sumAge = foldl' (+) 0
```

As for the average, you just sum and divide by the length:

```
averageAge :: [Double] -> Double
averageAge ls = sumAge ls / length ls
```

PS. In case your ages are integer, then the first function still works, but the average need to change:

```
averageInt :: [Int] -> Double
averageInt ls = (fromInteger . sum) ls / (fromInteger . length) ls
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `fromIntegral` on both numerator and denominator in order for the division to compile? (And the return type should of course be `Double` or similar, not `Int`.)

Comment: That is true, edited my answer. But I'd say it makes sense for the age to be a double so no need for `fromIntegral`?

Comment: True, in that case you don't need it. But then it's perfectly common to want to average a list of integers, and indeed people generally refer to ages as whole numbers.

Comment: I thought they might want to be more precise with animals as they are usually smaller ages, but ill put that in the answer

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR version

- Sum: `sumAges animals = foldl (\age animal -> age + (getAge animal)) 0 animals`
- Average:

```
import Data.Sequence(foldlWithIndex, fromList)

average numbers = foldlWithIndex (\a i x -> let k = fromIntegral i in (k*a + x) / (k + 1)) 0 . fromList $ numbers
```

### Long version

If you have an interest in math, it may help to understand the design of fold functions as equivalent to discovering sequence formulas by induction.

#### Sum

For sum, since you have `s[i+1] = s[i] + x[i+1]`, you can simply use addition like you did, although you may have to convert before you add:

```
sumAges :: [Animal] -> Int
sumAges animals = foldl (\age animal -> age + (getAge animal)) 0 animals

sumAgesPointFree :: [Animal] -> Int
sumAgesPointFree = foldl (flip $ (+) . getAge) 0
```

#### Average

For example, one way to calculate the average of a list using a single fold function is to use a recursive mathematical version of calculating the rolling average of a sequence: `m[i+1] = (i * m[i] + x[i+1]) / (i + 1)`.  You can see this in how you calculate the average of lists of varying sizes:

```
{-
  Not Haskell, just attempting mathematical notation without knowing MathML in Markdown.

  m: mean or average
  x: an element of a list or sequence
  []: subscript
 -}
m[1] = x[1]
m[2] = (x[1] + x[2]) / 2 = (m[1] + x[2]) / 2     -- m[1] = x[1], so substitute
m[3] = (x[1] + x[2] + x[3]) / 3                  -- (a+b)/n = a/n + b/n, so distribute
   = (x[1] + x[2]) / 3 + x[3] / 3                -- a = n/n * a, n not in {0, Infinity}
   = 2/2 * (x[1] + x[2]) / 3 + x[3] / 3          -- n/n * 1/a = n/a * 1/n
   = 2/3 * (x[1] + x[2]) / 2 + x[3] / 3          -- m[2] = (x[1] + x[2])/2, so substitute
   = 2/3 * m[2] + x[3] / 3
   = 2*m[2] / 3 + x[3] / 3
   = (2*m[2] + x[3]) / 3
...
m[i+1] = (i * m[i] + x[i+1]) / (i+1)
```

However, since this function would require the element index as a parameter, due to the List structure's lack of (convenient) indexing, the Sequence type from the `Data.Sequence` module may work out better than a List, especially considering the `Data.Sequence` module has this really nice `foldlWithIndex` function:

```hs
module Average(average) where
  import Data.Sequence(foldlWithIndex, fromList)

  average :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
  average = foldlWithIndex averageByPrevious 0 . fromList
    where averageByPrevious previous index current = (coefficient*previous + current) / (coefficient + 1)
            where coefficient = fromIntegral index
```

Then you can simply run `average list` where list is some list you want to find the rolling average of.  This is one way to calculate the average of a list using a single fold without adding a large performance overhead as you would by running multiple O(n) functions over the same list, even considering laziness as a benefit to the performance of multiple calls.

**NOTE**: I will admit, this is not easy to read, so `average xs = (sum xs) / (length xs)` as @Lorenzo said will work much better if legibility is more important than performance here.

Comment: or we could delay the calculations, use a pair as an accumulator, and put it through `uncurry (/)` as one post-processing step. your approach is great if we use it with `scanl`, not `foldl`.